# Why is my regex not matching blocks of numbers?

Tags: regex

pretty basic question, so I'll keep it short and sweet.

My current regex is `\d*` ( `(\d){1,6}` works, but is messy) - I want to grab all groups of numbers, i.e. `12345`, `857`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to do either `\d+` or `\d{1,}` to match/capture your groups of digits.

Regular expression quantifiers are as followed:

```
*      Match 0 or more times
+      Match 1 or more times
?      Match 1 or 0 times
{n}    Match exactly n times
{n,}   Match at least n times
{n,m}  Match at least n but not more than m times
```

As per stated with grabbing your last group of digits in the following string(s):

```
google.com/185/586 
google.com/389/754
```

Use a look ahead assertion: `(?<=\d\/)(\d+)`, this will capture (`586`) and (`754`)

Comment: Ah, of course, I screwed myself up by needlessly adding the plus in front of the first d, which shouldn't be necessary in a lookahead. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`\d*` matches any number of digits, including 0. Your string starts with 0 digits. Hey, a match!

Use `\d+`.

Comment: urgh, can't accept yet. Will accept as the answer when it lets me (12 minutes time)

Comment: Sorry about this, but a quick update (I'll add to the question) lookbehind doesn't seem to be working with that - if I try matching, say, the 56 in
123/56 with (?<=\d)56 nothing gets returned.

Comment: @Joe: The `56` in `123/56` isn't preceded by a digit; it's preceded by a slash.

Comment: It's an URL, it contains an id (which I don't need), followed by a slash, followed by another id (which I do need)

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, typo in my comment, I changed it at the last minute, should read
(?<=\d+\/)56

Comment: You mean? `(?<=\/)\d+`

Comment: Nah, that won't work unfortunately, there are multiple links in the text containing a slash followed by a number, so I need to match a number, preceded by a slash, preceded by another number.

Comment: What if the urls change? How do you know what you want to capture?

Comment: For that specific url, you can do it without a lookahead. `[^\/]+.*\/(\d+)`

Comment: Their format won't change, it's an each statement to grab each one. If the URL structure changes, I'll have bigger problems, as it'll mean the site it's based around has probably had a major redesign and so the entire script will have to be edited. the URLs will always be in the format
http://google.com/185/586
http://google.com/389/754
etc, where the last number block needs to be grabbed.

Comment: @hwnd that regex isn't working for me, regexr is matching every character.

Comment: (in those cases, the last number block would be classed as 586 and 754 respectively)

Comment: Try `\/.*\/(\d+)` or use a lookahead `(?<=\d{3}\/)(\d+)`